# Select custom strings and values without fields SQL

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I wonder how I can select custom values in SQL. I understand this is easy with MS SQL, but is it doable with PHPMyAdmin?

```
SELECT field1, 0 as answers FROM table

// "answers" should contain 0
```

The problem is that 0 is interpreted as a field, which it isn´t; it´s just a value I want to store in "answers".

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This looks like a bug in phpmyadmin. Considering that they had a long history of bugs like that, it's not surprising. Try working around it by not including "as answer", using an expression (say, (2-2) as answer), etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a constant, this should work:

```
SELECT field1, '0' as answers FROM table
```

Comment: Nope, Unknown column ''0'' in 'field list'

Comment: I just logged into some phpmyadmin and similar query worked for me.

Comment: Alright, then it must be my PHP that is wrong, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In MsSql

```
SELECT 'my value' AS COL1
```

or in Oracle for example

```
SELECT 'my value'FROM DUAL
```